# Proxy isn't working in Angular 13 and Springboot

Tags: angular, typescript, spring-boot-actuator

I'm having a problem with the proxy configuration inside Angular. I'm not sure if it's a problem in my Angular confs or if it's a configuration problem in Spring.

I have a backend made in springboot just for testing the frontend with simple requests.
When I make requests to the backend through Angular, I am getting a CORS error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/api/people/checks' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I have tried to create a proxy using the Angular [Documentation](https://angular.io/guide/build) to try to solve this problem, but it seems that the proxy is not running.

**proxy.conf.mjs**

```
export default [
  {
    context: ['/api'],
    target: 'http://localhost:8080',
    secure: false,
    logLevel: 'debug',
    // pathRewrite: { '^/api': '' }
  }
];
```

**angular.json**

```
"serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "clubzin:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "clubzin:build:development",
              "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.mjs"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        }
```

**enviroments.ts**

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  apiUrl: 'http://localhost:8080',
  username: 'danilo',
  password: '35bf85fe-c672-4d06-8cff-4485ed89211a',
  baseUrl: '/api'
};
```

**people.service.ts**

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CheckMail } from '../../home/model/check-mail';

import { environment } from '../../../environments/environment';

import { Buffer } from 'buffer';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PeopleService {

  private readonly API = `${environment.apiUrl}${environment.baseUrl}/people`;

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  checkMailInUse(mail: string) {
    let credential = Buffer.from(`${environment.username}:${environment.password}`).toString('base64');
    let headers = { Authorization: 'Basic ' + credential, mail: mail };
    let data = this.httpClient.get<CheckMail>(`${this.API}/checks`, { headers });
    return data;
  }

}
```

Finally, my question is, am I missing something? Or is it something from springboot that I need to configure as well?

**NOTE: When I add the CORS annotation in the controller, the request works.**

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the problem is not in the code. The problem is occurring because I am running the backend on windows and the frontend on WSL. When the proxy tries to hit localhost, it can't find the backend. After I migrated the code to Windows, the problem stopped occurring and the API began responding correctly.